# Use import/require in TypeScript to get interface declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript, js-amd

If I reference a TypeScript declarations file (ex. jquery.d.ts) using the `/// <reference path="..."/>` syntax, it's up to me to make sure I load the corresponding library by some other means, i.e. just referencing the .d.ts file doesn't load the library.

Is there a way to make TypeScript generate a `require()` call for the library when I use it? If I wasn't using AMD/requirejs I could just call `require` manually, but I'd like to get this to work with AMD.

The advantage of this is that my dependencies wouldn't be defined in two places. Referencing the library from a .ts file would be enough to make sure it loads, rather than having to maintain the list of dependencies manually in my HTML.

**Update**: I opened a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015898/asynchronous-load-of-typescript-declarations-with-no-exports) that clarifies my exact situation. I want to give credit for the answer to my original question since I didn't give all the necessary details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, TypeScript supports "external" modules, which are basically first class AMD or CommonJS modules. For example:

MyLib.ts

```
export function foo() { return 'bar' }
```

MyProj.ts

```
import lib = module('./MyLib.ts')
lib.foo(); // returns bar
```

Compile this with "--module amd" and you'll get the proper module and require syntax generated for you.

Comment: Modules work great for libraries that provide functions and variables directly, but I need something similar for libraries that extend existing functionality like jQuery plugins. There's nothing to export in those, but loading them adds additional calls on the JQuery interface (defined in jquery.d.ts)

Comment: In all fairness I think your answer does apply to my original question. I just failed to fully specify my question. I'll mark this as the answer and ask a clearer question.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [something](http://absolom-programming.blogspot.ca/2012/10/typescript-amd-with-js-library.html) about that on my blog. You can also find an example on [GitHub](https://github.com/joproulx/JsLibImporter).

The solution is rather long to explained, but basically I use shims with Require.JS to define a module name representing the Javascript library I want to load. I then create a TypeScript file with the same name to make the TypeScript compiler generates Javascript code that can use the JS library I want. Doesn't really makes sense like this, but please read the post and I think it will make more sense.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I don't think this solves my problem. This solution still assumes that the library has at least one top-level call so that TypeScript will generate the dependency in the `define` call. I don't have any top-level methods or variables since these libraries are plugins that extend existing functionality.

Also I don't think you really need to use shims in your example. If you just create an underscore.d.ts next to underscore.js you can import the 'libs/underscore' module and TypeScript will use the .d.ts file.

Comment: The d.ts file is only used by Typescript to determine if your code is correctly typed. Basically it's just an interface, so no code is generated by the Typescript compiler. You must provide the implementation of the Javascript library in some way. One solution is to reference a Javascript file in the html like you don't want to do. Another solution is to use AMD to load it asynchronously. That's the solution I propose.

Comment: Understood, but I still think that your solution is unnecessarily complex because of the shims.

Comment: Yes but I didn't find another simpler solution for this. Please note that this solution is good for libraries that you cannot modify like JQuery. I have seen your other question and I admit that's not exactly the case.

Comment: Why not just do `import underscore = module('libs/underscore');` and have a `libs/underscore.d.ts` file? That way TypeScript finds the declarations and the resulting code loads underscore without having to define any aliases. Also I assume you're using an older version of underscore that supports AMD-style loading. It looks like the latest version only supports the global '_'.

Comment: No, I am using the latest version of Underscore version without AMD-style loading. That's why I use the shim 'hack'. But the advantage is that a dev using your library only needs to refer to 'require.js' in its html. They don't have to refer to all the 'native' libraries like JQuery, Underscore, Sylvester, etc, that your Typescript refers to. You can check a small example on [GitHub](https://github.com/joproulx/JsLibImporter/tree/master/JsLibImporter) to see it in action.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I think I understand your solution now and why you use shims. The key reason I can't use this though is that a jQuery plugin has no top-level calls, so I can't declare any exports and get TypeScript to add the dependency in the generated code.