# Asynchronous load of TypeScript declarations with no exports

Tags: javascript, typescript, js-amd

I have a number of jQuery plugins that I would like to load using the AMD pattern in TypeScript. For example, I might have this structure:

```
/lib/jquery.myplugin.js
/app.ts
```

The plugin simply extends jQuery. It provides no new top-level functions or variables. An example might be:

```
// jquery.myplugin.js
jQuery.fn.myExample = function() { ... }
```

The corresponding jquery.myplugin.d.ts file looks like:

```
interface JQuery {
    myExample();
}
```

So that now in app.ts I can call something like `$('#my-element').myExample()`. Note that this assumes I already have the jquery.d.ts declarations from Microsoft loaded.

My question is how do I load this library asynchronously and take advantage of TypeScripts static typing? I could use it like this:

```
/// <reference path="lib/jquery.myplugin.d.ts"/>
```

but that requires me to add a `<script>` tag to my HTML, and the library is not loaded asynchronously. I want TypeScript to generate this code:

```
define(["require", "exports", "lib/jquery.myplugin"], function (require, exports, __jquery.myplugin__) {
    ...
    // Use my plugin
    $('#my-element').myExample();
}
```

However since there are no exports in the .d.ts file I can't write `import myplugin = module('lib/jquery.myplugin')`.

The closest I've gotten is to make a `jquery.myplugin.d.ts` that references another ts file with the interface declaration and includes at least one export. However there is nothing to export in this library, and in order to get the desired output I have to not only add an export but I have to call it.

**Update**: I have opened a [work item](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/318) for this on [typescript.codeplex.com](http://typescript.codeplex.com)

Comment: My current workaround is to manually call `require([...], () => { ... })` in my TypeScript code, which generates a nested require call. Far from ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript won't import modules unless they export something and unless you directly use what they exported, but those things aren't true for things like JQuery plugins that simply add new methods to $.  The solution is to use the amd-dependency flag as documented [here](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201410/Blog/TypeScript-AMD-Dependency-Comment/).

Add a line like this at the top of your file:

```
///<amd-dependency path="jgrowl" />
```

This will force Typescript to list it in the `define` invocation in the compiled Javascript.  You'll also need to set up a path and shim for your plugin in your require.config, like this:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: "external/jquery-2.1.1",
    jgrowl: "external/jquery.jgrowl-1.4.0.min",
  },
  shim: {
    'jgrowl': { deps: ['jquery'] },
  }
});
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much. I don't think this feature existed when I asked the question. This looks like exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Kind of a hack but here's the only way I currently know of.

*myplugin.d.ts*: extends the JQueryStatic interface to include intellisense for myplugin's functionality

```
/// <reference path="../dep/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

interface JQueryStatic {
    myFunc(): string;
}
```

*myplugin.ts*: a dummy file whose only purpose is to have typescript generate an amd module definition.

```
var test: number = 1;
```

*consumer.ts*:

```
/// <reference path="myplugin.d.ts" />

import myplugin = module('myplugin');

// without this typescript knows you aren't actually using the module
// and won't create the define block including your plugin
var workaround = myplugin.test;

$.myFunc();
```

*consumer.js*: generated with `tsc -c --module amd consumer.ts`

```
define(["require", "exports", 'myplugin'], function(require, exports, __myplugin__) {
    /// <reference path="myplugin.d.ts" />
    var myplugin = __myplugin__;

    // without this typescript knows you aren't actually using the module
    // and won't create the define block including your plugin
    var workaround = myplugin.test;
    $.myFunc();
})
```

Note that *myplugin.d.ts* will pull intellisense in for both jQuery and your plugin  definitions. It was necessary to create both a myplugin.d.ts and myplugin.ts because I don't know how (if possible) to export something while simultaneously extending an existing interface in the same file without errors.

Comment: It seems you'd also have to define a path in the requirejs config (or whatever AMD loader you're using) that associates 'myplugin' with the path to the plugin, correct? Otherwise, if you put myplugin.d.ts in the same location as the plugin, the compiled js file will overwrite your plugin library.

Comment: Only if you ran the compiler with the definitions flag and didn't specify an alternate output directory. It will just output myplugin.js by default.

Comment: I'm saying that myplugin.js is probably your library's name in this case. In my example I would have imported 'lib/jquery.myplugin'. So without aliasing the dependency name, your generated JavaScript file will overwrite your library.

Comment: @dcstraw it won't overwrite your library as it will create a file named `myplugin.d.js` not `myplugin.js`.

Comment: @Sohnee I've never seen tsc generate a .d.js file. There is no output for a .d.ts file, and a .ts file generates a .js file.

Comment: I see what you mean. Yes I have a similar problem like this with no solution yet as well

Comment: @dcstraw if you are using Visual Studio there will be a `d.js` file, but it never gets used.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the file that the interface is defined within you can put:

```
export var JQuery: JQueryStatic;
```

Which will make the intellisense for JQuery show up on any file loaded using `import module`.

If your file is being loaded asynchronously and you're setting **JQuery** to another variable (i.e. **myJQuery**) you can declare that the file has already been loaded by a certain point, for example, if you have the file in your `///<reference path=...>` you should be able to use:

```
declare var myJQuery: JQuery;
```

To make your **myJQuery** of type **JQuery**.

Another hack is to insert the interface directly into the area where the code is being loaded asynchronously:

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    myFunc(): string;
}
```

If you don't mind editing your JQuery.d.ts files, you can add your function to the interfaces defined in there.

Related back to your example, you should be able to do something like:

```
declare var __jquery : JQueryStatic;
```

At the top of your define callback; and provided you've extended the interface for **JQueryStatic** and included it using `///<reference path=...>` the markup should work as desired.

Comment: I haven't used AMD myself, but I hope that this helps!

Comment: Declaring global variables works fine for libraries that you load through some other means, ex. a script tag in your HTML. The benefit of the AMD pattern is that it lets you declare your dependency and have it loaded as needed or bundled in at build time, and your global namespace doesn't have to get polluted. That specifically is what is not well supported in TypeScript for libraries that have no top-level exports.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that the AMD pattern worked off a callback style? If so then wouldn't it be possible to declare a variable with the JQuery interface in the callback?
Then it would show up for intellisense only within the callback and not in the rest of the file.

Comment: The issue isn't with the capabilities of the AMD pattern, but with TypeScript's integration between modules and the AMD pattern. There's no way to make the TypeScript compiler generate the proper `define` call using modules in the current implementation.

Comment: Ok, I understand. You wanted to generate the `define` function all along. I thought you just wanted `intellisense` for all of the variables declared in your callback's parameter listing. Sorry! :)